# how to bend text in as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a text 'hello world' in my ActionScript3 file.

What I am trying to achieve is to make the middle portion of the text bigger in height.

So, it will start off with a small 'h' and then moving towards the middle, each letter's size will increase.

The exact thing is shown in this image -

[image: helloworld]
http://img180.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=96687_helloworld_122_632lo.jpg

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this has per-glyph distortion, the only way to do it correctly is with a [DisplacementMapFilter](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html) (which would actually work well with animation too). [Here's](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/12/03/understanding-flash-displacement-map-filter/) a good example on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `drawTriangles` from `Graphics` object.
First, create a `BitmapData` and do a copy of your `TextField` (enlarged).
Then you just have to map your BitmapData to a bended mesh (made of triangles).

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this, I would put every character in a separate TextField, every TextField in a Sprite, set a proper font size for every character, place the Sprites on proper positions and distort the Sprites using whatever methods you need (Transformation Matrix, 3D, whatever).